# electron app.on() undefined error , how to fix it ?

Tags: javascript, electron

Please help me to fix this issue here some code examples .

```
1. 
    const electron = require('electron');
    const app = electron.app;
    const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

    function createWindow(){
        win = new BrowserWindow({width:800,height:600});
        win.loadFile('views/index.html');
    }

    app.on('ready',createWindow);
```

2. When i am using the electron-prebuilt library  i don't have the app and BrowserWindow functionality  :

   > > const electronpre = require('electron-prebuilt');
3. I deleted and installed electron couple times globally and not globally.

   How can i fix the problem ?

I tried:

```
"electron": "^4.0.0",
"electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
```

Answer (score -1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-prebuilt

> electron-prebuilt has been renamed to electron. For more details, see http://electron.atom.io/blog/2016/08/16/npm-install-electron

electron-prebuilt is old version name of electron's binary package and you shouldn't install it along with electron. Just install electron package and import necessary namespace.

Comment: Are you sure you saw mine question ?

Comment: The first 1 paragraph in mine question is not working .

Comment: well my answer is #2 you pointed, and you haven't shared any error messages for 1 and asking why error occurs?